# can not assign date to ui-date angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-datepicker

I want to assign my string date to ui-date

my view

```
 <input ng-switch-when="datePicker" type="text" ui-date-format ui-date class="form-control" ng-model="field.value" />
```

and my date string 
"12/12/2015"

but I got this error "Error: ng-Model value must be a Date object - currently it is a string - use ui-date-format to convert it from a string"

Please someone help me, thank

Answer (score 1):

Try doing as it says (*Error: ng-Model value must be a Date object*) in controller

```
$scope.field.value = new Date($scope.field.value);
```

Or add an [date-format attribute](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date#ui-date-format-directive) with your date mask to the input tag

```
ui-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY"
```

Comment: I have tried your first option,It's not error,  but the view (input) is blank
the second option , I still got the same error.

Comment: oh, sorry thats should be - ui-date-format="mm/dd/yy"

Comment: could you show all the code html/js of your case? - seems that something else results this error

Comment: I can not reply your comment with code style, so i have posted other answer for you

Comment: ohhhh, its a mess >_<  can you in your template add near to this line ' <input ng-switch-when="datePicker" type="text" ui-date-format="mm/dd/yy"  ui-date class="form-control" ng-model="field.value" />' the following - '{{field.value}}' - so that we can see what value is there

Comment: IT shows 12/12/2015 , while JSON "12/12/2015"
and In textbox "Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)" and got a error like I mention in question

Comment: let's remove type="text" attribute from that input

Comment: still the same, I think the problem is about ng-model.

Comment: did you remove that line '$scope.field.value = new Date($scope.field.value);' I wrote initially? that should not be there

Comment: could you maybe reproduce the full code of your case in http://codepen.io or http://plnkr.co/ ? we're definitely missing something obvious, but it's hard to debug code in your mind